# Pause in Java + end method

Tags: java, greenfoot

I wanted to say for a school project in Greenfoot, that if a rover encounters a system error, it should output this and then wait a short time and then terminate the current method. However, the pause is marked with the following error code: unreported exception java. lang. InterupptedException; must be cought or declared to be thrown, as I am very new to Java I have no idea what to change. Besides, he should then end the method, but with the current command the whole scenario is ended.

"

```
public Rover (String pname, char pfrequenz, int penergie)
{
    energie = penergie;
    name = pname;
    temp = 15 ;
    distance = 0;
    systemcheck = true;
    frequenz = pfrequenz ;
}

public void check()
{
    if (markeVorhanden())
    {
        energie = energie + 100;
    }
    if (energie == 0){
        systemcheck = false;

    }
    if (systemcheck = false){
        nachricht("System Failure");
        java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
         System.exit(0);
    }
    if (distance > 100){
        nachricht("Congrats you have passed 100");
    }
    anzeige.anzeigen("Akku:  "+energie+ "  %");
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a typo in `if (systemcheck = false){`. You want *two* `=` signs, otherwise the condition will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read up on exception handling in Java. The `sleep` method may get interrupted and may thus raise an `InterruptedException`. You can either forward this exception or ignore it.
To forward the exception, declare the function a

```
public void check() throws InterruptedException
```

but then callers of this function will have to deal with that potential exception. Since interrupted does not look a severe problem here (the sleep is just a bit shorter than the two seconds), it may be fine to ignore the exception:

```
try { java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); }
catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
```

In order to just return from the current method use `return` instead of `System.exit()`

Comment: When I use this I can't youse the method just simply with check(); in other methods how to write them?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? If you just ignore the exception then things should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.io.*;

public class Yourclass{



public void Rover (String pname, char pfrequenz, int penergie)
{
    Integer energie = penergie;
    String name = pname;
    Integer temp = 15 ;
    Integer distance = 0;
    boolean systemcheck = true;
    char frequenz = pfrequenz ;
}

public  void check() throws IOException
{

    if (markeVorhanden())
    {
        energie = energie + 100;
    }
    if (energie == 0){
        systemcheck = false;

    }


    if (systemcheck = false){
        nachricht("System Failure");
        throw new IOException("sorry device error");  
    }
    if (distance > 100){
        nachricht("Congrats you have passed 100");
    }
    anzeige.anzeigen("Akku:  "+energie+ "  %");


}


 public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException
 {
     Yourclass demo= new Yourclass();
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    try{
        demo.check();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       System.out.println("function stopped"); 
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: So there is still one Error:
public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException
 {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    try{
        check();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       System.out.println("function stopped"); 
    }
 }

The check(); is marked and gives the Error: non-static method check() cannot be referenced from static context